# JavaScript audio recorder with pause and resume functionality

Tags: performance, audio, client-side, audio-recording, jrecorder

I was looking for javascript audio with pause and resume functionality.

I had a look at [jRecorder](http://www.sajithmr.me/jrecorder-jquery) but it is also not providing the pause button.

I assume someone has already faced such situation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. It has the following features: - pause recording - pause playback - record time callback - upload the recorded audio - only upload button is inside flash

DOWNLOAD: https://github.com/ehsan6sha/FlashWavRecorder